# Concept of noise floor

Tags: noise

Can anyone please explain the concept of noise floor. If we want to design an active high pass filter with a cut off frequency of 12 kHz and pass band gain of 2, how do we apply the concept of noise floor in this design?

Comment: No research effort - question should be closed.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that your input doesn't have noise (clearly not true, but bear with me), the active circuit that filters your signal will introduce noise and this noise will be increased in-line with the gain of the circuit.

If you are using op-amps, one of the parameters contained in the data sheet is E(noise). This is the basic noise that the op-amp produces and is wideband in nature. It is basically white noise and has a spectral density of so-many watts per hertz BUT it is usually specified as volts per sqrt(hertz).

How do you use it?

Say the figure is 10 nV/\$\sqrt{Hz}\$ and, if you have a bandwidth that is limited to precisely 12 kHz, take the square root of 12,000 (109.5) and multiply it by 10 nV to get a total noise (referred to the op-amp input) of 1.2 uV RMS.

This is subject to a gain of 2 (as per the question) giving you an output amplitude of 2.4 uV RMS. You can use stats to convert this to a peak-to-peak voltage by multiplying it by 6.6. This produces a peak-to-peak value that is statistically guaranteed to be below 14.4 uV p-p for 99.9% of the time: -

[image]

The above taken from [Op-amp noise relationships, MT-048 by ADI](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.analog.com%2Fmedia%2Fen%2Ftraining-seminars%2Ftutorials%2FMT-048.pdf&ei=kHRtVeLeKoaw7AaD54CADg&usg=AFQjCNFy-1-7cIZAnd5XRb1X3-_JNDd2LA&bvm=bv.94455598,d.ZGU).

There are other noise sources too.

- Flicker noise is also specified in op-amp data sheets and this covers the range from 0.1 Hz to 10 Hz (usually) and is stated as a p-p value.
- Input bias current noise is also specified and this manifests itself as a voltage depending on the resistance connected to each op-amp input.
- Resistor [thermal noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Nyquist_noise). Every resistor produces noise and this has to be factored in especially if high values are used.

All these factors need to be added together as RMS values like: -

Addition = \$\sqrt{A^2+B^2+C^2+etc}\$

Finally, for a bandwidth of 12 kHz, you should analyse noise up to a bandwidth that can be significantly greater than 12 kHz. The effective [noise bandwidth](http://www.onmyphd.com/?p=enbw.equivalent.noise.bandwidth) is always bigger: -

[image]

The above tells you that for a single order low pass filter circuit at 12kHz, the noise bandwidth that should be taken into account is 1.5708 x 12 kHz. For a 2nd order filter the noise bandwidth is 1.1107 x 12 kHz.

Further reading: [Op-amp noise, MT-047 by ADI](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCoQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.analog.com%2Fmedia%2Fen%2Ftraining-seminars%2Ftutorials%2FMT-047.pdf&ei=GnBtVcXEM8qP7Aaa-YDICw&usg=AFQjCNExEw3641WxW4-O1YeudwuQ7CLyMw&bvm=bv.94455598,d.ZGU).

---

### EDIT/ADDITION

Usually op-amps have a graph that shows how the noise density figure changes across the spectrum. Below is the AD8665: -

[image]

Note that only at 1kHz is the E(noise) a value of 10 nV/\$\sqrt{Hz}\$. Some designs my operate well above 1kHz and you can realize a better noise figure providing the low frequencies are filtered out after the amplifier. Note also that the noise at 100 Hz is, for this op-amp, 20 nV/\$\sqrt{Hz}\$ so if you have a particular design that is aiming at this frequency range then use the higher noise figures.

Comment: Hi Andy,Thank you very much for your time and concern.Coud please define what is noise floor.i mean its definition.

Comment: Wiki is good for this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noise_floor

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to add that there can be other sources of noise besides the opamps you use. Capacitors and Inductors are generally considered NOT to add noise. However, resistors do add noise !

If you are using resistors in your filter design (for example as feedback path for the opamps) then their noise must be taken into account. The (thermal) noise of a resistor is 4kTR so proportional to the value of the resistor. This means that higher value resistors will generate more noise and thus increase the noise floor.
For low value resistors their noise might be so low that the opamps determine the noise floor.

If you have access to a circuit simulator (qucs is a free example) you can simulate your filter with ideal opamps and determine the noise floor of your design.